# if values matches do addition of related attributes in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays

$firstArr :

```
Array
(
    [0] => doratest
    [1] => test564
)
```

and

$secondArr:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [aid] => test564
            [aidCount] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [aid] => doratest
            [aidCount] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [aid] => nmtTest
            [aidCount] => 1
        )

)
```

If values of `$firstArr` found in `$secondArr` then I need to do addition of their respective `aidCount`.
So in above case finalCount should be 3.

I have done something like below but that giving wrong count. And I am confused how should I modify below code to get correct answer. I am not sure if I used `array_intersect` of `$detailsAIDs` and `$firstArr` then how should I do addition of related `aidCount`.

```
 foreach($secondArras $key2 => $details) {

        array_push($detailsAIDs, $details['aid']);

              if (in_array($details['aid'], $firstArr ))
              {
                   $finalCount  = $details['aidCount'];
             } 
                     
     }
```

Please help and guide. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are adding something to something, then I would expect `+` sign somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Use nested for to check the same element, and add it to your `finalCount` variable.

```
$finalCount = 0;
foreach($firstArr as $details)
{
    foreach($secondArr as &$row)
    {
        if($details == $row['aid'])
        {
            $finalCount += $row['aidCount']++;
        }
    }
}
//echo $finalCount;
```

Comment: Actually I don't want to modify $secondArray. just need to get addition of related aidCount in another variable.

Comment: so in the example, you need the addition `aidCount` of `doratest` and `test564`?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$arr1 = Array('doratest', 'test564');
$arr2 = Array(
          Array('aid' => 'test564', 'aidCount' => 1), 
          Array('aid' => 'doratest', 'aidCount' => 2), 
          Array('aid' => 'nmtTest', 'aidCount' => 1)
);

foreach($arr1 as $item) {
    foreach($arr2 as &$data) {
        if($data['aid'] == $item) {
            $data['aidCount'] = $data['aidCount'] + 1;
            continue;
        }
    }
}

print_r($arr2);

/* Output:

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [aid] => test564
            [aidCount] => 2
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [aid] => doratest
            [aidCount] => 3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [aid] => nmtTest
            [aidCount] => 1
        )

)
```